# Convert Magnetic North to True North

Tags: windows-8.1, compass-geolocation

I have got a question for you guys since it gets worst when you start missing tiny things from your hardware specs or your software APIs.

I'm developing a Windows Store app that works with a compass and it is obvious that our current laptops (most of them) are not having any compass sensors built in. Therefore, it would only run on tablets like Surface RT etc.

The problem is; I need to work with a true north and the compass Surface RT works / supports only magnetic north. I would like to know if anyone knows a way to convert magnetic north to true north by some mathematical calculations?

Appreciate your answers.

Thanks!

Comment: The relationship between magnetic and true north is not deterministic: you'd have to rely on published tables.

Comment: You certainly cannot do it without access to the geographical location, at least. Seeing as how you assume you're on a tablet, you may or may not have that.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO is the right place for this (Math Stack Exchange might be better), but as far as implementation goes, you need one more piece of information--the angle deviation between mag. and true north is dependent on location. So you will need to get a rough location. IP address should be sufficient for most applications.

Comment: An introduction to the underlying problem: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/declination.shtml

Answer (score 0):

To convert magnetic north to True north you need a geo magnetic earth model.

One of that is the geomagnetic earth modell, developped by NOAA.
You can download the source and implement that too: Geomag: http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/

It is a set of curves which are interpolated for the given location.

Apple uses that in iOS, it is Open source and is listed in their Open source info.

Comment: The link from NOAA is dead and Apple has a LOT of open source. Do you know what class these conversion are in? Thanks!

Comment: If the link is dead, please research the current location and update the  link.